# How to save snapshot without showing SaveFileDialog?

Tags: c#

I want to take snapshot from the webcam and save it in a given path.The webcam should start after a given time period.This is the code I have tried it works properly but I don't need to popup SaveFileDialog when the file is saving.How do I save the snapshot without showing SaveFileDialog? Please help.....

```
private void btnStartPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int delay = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
        int miliseconds = delay * 1000;
        Thread.Sleep(miliseconds);
        this.Refresh();

        cm = new VideoCaptureDevice(wcam[cmbDevice.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        cm.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_newFrame);
        cm.Start();

        String path = txtBrowse.Text;

        string currentDateTime = string.Format("text-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.bin", DateTime.Now);

        SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
        s.FileName = currentDateTime + ".jpg";
        s.DefaultExt = ".Jpg";
        s.Filter = currentDateTime + "(.jpg)|*.jpg";


        s.InitialDirectory = @path;

        if (s.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            pictureBox1.Image.Save(s.FileName);

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the answer yourself:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(s.FileName);
```

The first parameter is a file name, so you can provide it with a `string` if you want.

Samples:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\test\picture.jpg");

pictureBox1.Image.Save(Path.Combine("folder", "filename"));

string s = ...

pictureBox1.Image.Save(s);
```

Comment: @user3387002: Since you are new here, please don't forget to mark the question as answered if the answer was sufficient. Please see the [FAQ#why-vote]

Comment: Do you need more help? If not, please close this question by marking it as answered.